# I have a short and a long stick OR sticks?

Tags: nouns

What is the correct version of the sentence?

1. I have a short and a long stick.
2. I have a short and a long sticks.

Comment: Please write the 2 sentences separately, so that it's clear what the 2 sentences are.

Comment: Hello dart,  I can see what the sentences are, but just writing two sentences and asking which one is correct is not a good type of question.  Do you **really** want to talk to someone about your sticks?  If not, what is the real problem that brought you to this site?

Answer (score 4):

The first version is correct.  The "full" version of this sentence would be "I have a short stick and a long stick". Leaving out non-essential words like this is known as ellipsis.  Another example would be "I have a summer and a winter jacket."

The second "a" is important.  If you said "I have a short and long stick," you would be referring to one stick that is both short and long.

The plural "sticks" would be correct if you said "I have short and long sticks."  However, that sentence does not tell us how many sticks you have.

Answer (score 0):

The first is correct grammaticially. But The first doesn't make sense. Its meaning is "I have one stick that is both short and long. A stick cannot be both short and long at the same time.  It is so odd that people might assume you meant "I have a short stick and a long stick", but compare with:

> I have a big and heavy stick.

Is correct and means that the stick is both big and heavy.

The second is incorrect grammatically, because the singular article  "a" can't be used with the plural noun "sticks"

If you have a mixture of long sticks and short sticks you could say

> I have long sticks and short sticks.

or perhaps

> I have both long and short sticks.

Comment: -1 you are missing the 2nd use of the indefinite article in the original example, which makes it clear that exactly two sticks are being mentioned The parallel would be "*I have a big and **a** heavy stick*" which should likewise refer to 2 sticks, although that is less clear since "big" and "heavy" are n ot ,opposites.